# Voltmeter across a circular wire in a changing magnetic field -- revisited

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

The old puzzle is pretty standard: You have a circular wire with a small resistor somewhere and you put it in a changing magnetic field, in the plane normal to the field.  Then you hook a voltmeter across the diameter and what do you get?  The standard answer comes from applying Kirchoff's rules across the various loops in the problem, with the EMF applied by the magnetic field, and you get zero.

So there's no need to look at the electric field.  We can just rely on EMF.  But, I would think, we can look at this problem from the point of view of electric field if we want to.  The problem is that electric field $\mathbf{E}$ is given by

$\displaystyle
\nabla\times\mathbf{E} = - \frac{\partial \mathbf{B}}{\partial t}$

taking $c=1$.

We know the RHS here, but even with that given, there are an infinite number of electric field configurations that can satisfy this equation.  One such would be

$\displaystyle \mathbf{E} =  \frac{dB}{dt}\frac{r}{2} \hat{\mathbf{\phi}}$

with $r$ measured from the center of the loop and $\phi$ pointing along the polar angle direction.  In this case the electric field always points normal to the leads attaching the voltmeter to the loop and will never drive current across it, so it's pretty clear that the voltmeter would read zero.

But $\mathbf{E}$ could also be

$\displaystyle \mathbf{E} = \frac{dB}{dt}x\mathbf{\hat{y}}$

In this case, if we attach the voltmeter leads so they lie on a loop diameter in the $\mathbf{\hat{y}}$ direction, the e-field points right along the wires and, to me anyway, it is no longer clear at all that we should expect no reading on the voltmeter.  How is it that the voltmeter still registers no potential change?

Comment: In one place, you write "the wire holding the voltmeter" and in another, you write "the voltmeter wire".  But a voltmeter has *two* leads and it's important to know whether there is changing magnetic flux threading the loop formed by these leads or not.  I suggest that you add a diagram to make the experimental set-up clearer.

Comment: I don't think that your first proposed solution for E satisfies the requirement that the divergence of E is zero, and your second proposed solution for E lacks circular symmetry.

Comment: @SamuelWeir  In my first solution, E depends only on radius but points only in the azimuthal direction.  divE must therefore be zero.  My second solution certainly lacks circular symmetry.  Maybe that's another way of asking my question: Why assume circular symmetry of the E field?  Symmetry of the problem notwithstanding, I don't see why a lab experiment couldn't be set up where the field lacks circular symmetry.

Comment: @HalHollis  Edited and tried to clarify.  Not in a position to add diagrams right now.  Sorry.